# Calculating line length in Java

Tags: java, fontmetrics

I've been using LineBreakMeasurer & AttributedString to measure line lengths. However, I now need to take into account:

1. Small Caps
2. Scaling (making each character thinner/wider).
3. Spacing (adding/subtracting space after each character).
4. Hyphenation, where line breaks can occur at specific places within words.

Is there a way to do this using Java? The two fundamental things I need to get is:

1. How long is a passed in string.
2. For a passed in string and length, how many characters of the string fits in that length.

I can do this using LineBreakMeasurer & AttributedString and calling it character by character. But is there a better way?

thanks - dave